# How to enable IPv6 on subinterface in Linux using sysctl?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, systemctl, sysctl

I tried the following:
`sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.Ethernet1.200.disable_ipv6=0`,
but it gave following error:

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/Ethernet1/200/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
```

It should have ideally tried to change in
`/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/Ethernet1.200/disable_ipv6`

which it is not

I have used `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/Ethernet1.200/disable_ipv6`,
but I need some Linux command that does the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because sysctl.conf uses dots as filesystem path separators, you have to use `/` in place of actual dots. Yes, it's weird like that.

```
net.ipv6.conf.Ethernet1/200.disable_ipv6 = 0
```

But you can actually use `/` as the separator, too:

```
net/ipv6/conf/Ethernet1.200/disable_ipv6 = 0
```

I would honestly suggest *not* disabling IPv6 by default; then the problem would be avoided.